# Spring WebMVC - ModelAttribute with null values in controller

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc, modelattribute, spring-form

I read through [the similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25751254/modelattribute-returns-null-values-in-controller-in-spring-mvc) and unfortunately didn't find a solution.
I am sending a Student entity as `@ModelAttribute` to my JSP, allowing user to edit it. When the Student is POST'ed back to the controller (`StudentController`) the fields `rates` and `id` are null. Null value for `rates` is OK, I pass student's rates as a separate `@RequestParam`. Other fields are OK. But `id` is unexpectedly null.
I am using Java 8, Spring 4.1, Tomcat 7.0.55, JSTL 1.2.

Here is a relevant part of my `StudentController`:

```java
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/student")
public class StudentController {

    @Autowired
    private StudentService studentService;
    @Autowired
    private FacultyService facultyService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView editStudentPage(@PathVariable Long id) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("student-edit");

        Student student = (id > 0)? studentService.findById(id) : new Student();
        mav.addObject("student", student);
        // or
        //mav.getModelMap().addAttribute(student);

        /* other objects omitted */

        return mav;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/edit/{id:.+}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ModelAndView editStudent(
            @ModelAttribute Student student,
            @RequestParam(value="rates", required = false) String ratesString,
            @PathVariable Long id,
            final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) throws StudentNotFoundException {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView("redirect:/student/list");

        student = studentService.update(student);
        student.updateRates(ratesString);

        String msg = "Student was successfully updated";
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", msg);
        return mav;
    }

    /* ... */
}
```

Here is a student-edit JSP file:

```html
<jsp:useBean id="student" scope="request" class="by.naxa.demo.model.Student" />
<!-- I've tried to comment out the above line in order to avoid collision with `modelAttribute` (in hope that this was a culprit) -->
<%@page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib prefix="c"    uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>

<c:url var="formAction" value="/student/edit/${student.id}" /> <!-- simplified -->

<!-- <head> omitted -->
<body>
<form:form action="${formAction}" method="POST" modelAttribute="student" >
    <form:hidden path="id" /> <!-- I've tried to specify `value="${student.id}"` here -->

    <div>
        <form:label path="name">Student's name:</form:label>
        <form:input path="name" required="true"/><br />
        <!-- other fields omitted -->

        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        <!-- `Cancel` omitted -->
    </div>
</form:form>
</body>
```

I see that inputs on a generated page are populated with right values:

```html
<input id="id" name="id" value="1" type="hidden" />
<input id="name" name="name" required="true" type="text" value="John Snow"/>
```

web.xml:

```xml
<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/app/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jsp</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/WEB-INF/views/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file />
</welcome-file-list>
```

ViewResolver in Spring servlet-context.xml:

```xml
<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

Class Student extends AbstractNamedPersistable. Here they are (annotated with Lombok and JPA):

```java
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = true)
@ToString(callSuper = true, includeFieldNames = false)
@NamedQuery(name = "Student.findByTheStudentsName", query = "select s from Student s where s.name = ?1")
public @Data class Student extends AbstractNamedPersistable<Long> {
    /* all fields and `updateRates(String)` omitted */
}

@MappedSuperclass
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public abstract @Data class AbstractNamedPersistable<PK extends Serializable> extends AbstractPersistable<PK> {

    @Column(name = "Name", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
}
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29039116/how-to-partially-update-record-with-spring-mvc-and-use-post-redirect-get-patte

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, thank you, i've used a [`@SessionAttributes`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/SessionAttributes.html) to store `Student` in a session context, and [Converter](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/convert/converter/package-summary.html)s to convert `rates` between `List<Integer>` (field) and `String` (input).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue(bug) with Lombok I guess, when we use @NoArgsConstructor with a request which is attributed as @ModelAttribute, it overrides the request params with a default constructor as it is attributed with @ModelAttribute and not @RequestBody, so the JSON Body overrides the fields passed in query string .
The way to avoid this is to remove @NoArgsConstructor annotation for request pojos annotated with @ModelAttribute.